# How to resend data from parent to child once ngIf becomes true?

Tags: angular

I am using observable to pass data to child components. These child components can be enabled and disabled with ngIf. Problem occurs when I re-enable such component, it simply cannot get data because .next() was fired long time ago, and passing already collected data once more using .next() doesn't work because value is emitted before child component is recreated.

Example:

```
// parentComponent.ts
this.dataService.getData().then(data => this.data$.next(data););

// parentComponent.html
<app-component1 ngIf="view === 1" [data$]="data$"></app-component1>
<app-component2 ngIf="view === 2" [data$]="data$"></app-component2>

// childComponent.ts
@Input() data$: Subject<any>;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.sub = this.data$.subscribe((data) => {
  this.data = data;
});
```

}

Any ideas on how to pass same data again from parent to child components once they are constructed again (ngIf = true)?

Comment: Show your code for the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guessing you want to be using a `ReplaySubject` instead of a `Subject`.. something like:

```
data$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

this will cache and re emit 1 value to new subscribers.